# UWP: AccessViolationException on an attempt to open a page

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, access-violation

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that uses FreshMvvm. On an attempt to open a particular page with this code:

```
await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<DistributorsLocatorPageModel>();
```

after the execution passes the page's Init() method and all properties, the app crashes with the following error:

> System.AccessViolationException
>
> HResult=0x80004003
>
> Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> Source=Cannot evaluate the exception source
>
> StackTrace: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

This happens only in UWP. iOS and Android have no issue. And other pages also open fine even in UWP.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Anything running on the Page Init() or Constructor? If any try commenting it out.

Comment: @pinedax I left both constructor and Init() empty... with the same result...

Answer (score 0):

just found this through desperate googling and didn't find much in the way of answers.

one thing i'll say for it is that the issue lies in thread safety - when navigation is done explicitly on the main thread the problem doesn't arise, however if you're using AppShell navigation on a tabpage or some other place where you don't invoke the navigation in your own code, there doesn't seem to be a lot you can do.

I'm currently attempting to find a good place to override OnNavigatedTo, but so far have come up short.

so I guess this is a long way of saying "bump"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).